# JavaScript won't execute in ASP.NET view code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET (4 weeks in), and this question looks similar to many others I've explored through this site...but none of them seem to work for me.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The web app I'm developing on (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET 16.0 MVC) is a planning tool for jobs (HPCJob) on a cluster.  The "Create" page is where I have multiple controls.  The front end of the Create.cshtml is below:

```
@model HPCPlanner.HPCJob

@using HPCPlanner.Controllers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
</script>

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@*bunch of HTML controls*@

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The relevant Controller code is simple:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: HPCJobs/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "JobID,ClusterUserID,ProjectName,AnalysisDesc,JobQueue,CoresNeeded,StartDate,StartTime,EndDate,EndTime,Duration")] HPCJob hPCJob)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.HPCJobs.Add(hPCJob);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(hPCJob);
    }
```

I've been trying to get the JavaScript at the top of the Create view to execute, and use it to enable/disable the controls on the page.  However, not matter what I do, that JavaScript doesn't seem to execute.  As a final attempt, I simplified it to just show me an alert when the page loads...and that also doesn't seem to execute.  After spending days looking for answers on the net, and in this forum, I'm still lost.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.  I can't move forward without figuring out why this won't work.

Comment: Open up your developer console in the browser and see, if any errors pop up. Personally, I'd put that alert code in the Scripts section of the view. Then ake sure, that jquery is loaded before that scripts section is rendered in your layout file.

Comment: Since the `<script` block comes before the Script.Render command, I'd say there's a good chance it errors because jquery isn't loaded yet (although of course I don't know what's in your script bundle, but that's my assumption). As Marco says, you can verify it by checking your browser's console.